# Date/DateTime format in environment evaluates only on a to_s call, is this an overhead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, format, tostring

I have this in my environment.rb,

```
my_datetime_formats = { :default => "%F - %T" } 
my_date_formats = { :default => '%F -' } 

Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(my_datetime_formats)
Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(my_date_formats)
```

In my rails console,

```
1.9.3p385 :002 > p User.find(1).created_at
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1

Wed, 04 Dec 2013 22:27:43 UTC +00:00 # note this format, undesirable

1.9.3p385 :003 > p User.find(1).created_at.to_s
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1

"2013-12-04 - 22:27:43"# note this format, DESIRABLE
```

So now, I figured out, the to_s method actually evaluates the right format.

This is approach I use to render columns as a table in my view,

```
 @cols = [:name,:email,:date_of_birth,:gender,:address,:mobile,:created_at]
 @cols.map{|i| temp << enq.send(i.to_s).to_s } # note the to_s method here.
```

My question is, only in order to display date_of_birth and created_at in the desired format, **Im calling to_s on (name, email, gender, address, mobile), is this an overhead? or am i over reacting??**

**What would to_s do, if its called on a String**. Ex: "string".to_s. I know it returns "string", but work does ruby do internally??

> **Why to_s is required to evaluate the date/time format???????????**

Comment: The answer to your second question is easy to find in the [source](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_s).

Answer (score 1):

There are several questions in here as far as I can see.

1. Why do the outputs differ in the console

   AFAIK the default output in IRB uses `inspect` instead of `to_s`.
2. Am I overreacting

   Yes! There is no performance penalty here, at least you won't be able to measure it unless you are running on a digital watch.
3. What does `to_s` do on an instance of `String`

   See the link in the comments, it just returns itself.
4. Why to_s is required to evaluate the date/time format?

   It is not required, see Nr 1.